# Joblib: how to kill orphaned semaphores?

Tags: python-3.x, joblib

I have orphaned semaphores on a vm I would not like to reboot after signal inerrupting a joblib task.

```
kill pid
```

is not working.  How do I kill the semaphores? they are locking out joblib parallelism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that while `kill` and `top` were insufficient, using `htop` in conjunction with the `F9` signal interruption/terminate/etc. palette and manual brute force methods on the orphaned process list did the task.  The semaphores had to be killed first, some signals worked some of the time and others worked at other times.

The `dask` library used as the parallel backend is my prime suspect for orphaning the semaphores, as it also had a memory leak.